# Deserialize nested interfaces

Tags: c#, json.net

Reproduction can be seen here: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/metanoic/ca49b17581c79b7e009ab135beb46d5e).

I'm receiving an error when attempting to deserialize a collection of interfaces - particularly where the interface also contains a collection of the same interfaces.  If I remove the nested collection, it deserializes fine.  I had thought that implementing the JsonConverter would handle this, but I seem to be misunderstanding something.

Note that I do not have control over the serialization.

The error I'm receiving is:

> Could not create an instance of type JsonRepro.IMember. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'members[0].id', line 17, position 25.

Minimal reproduction is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace JsonRepro
{
    public interface IMember
    {
        int ID { get; set; }
        string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class A : IMember
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public List<IMember> Members { get; set; }
    }

    public class B : IMember
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return typeof(IMember).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
            Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject item = JObject.Load(reader);
            var typeValue = item["type"].Value<string>();

            switch (typeValue)
            {
                case "A":
                    return item.ToObject<A>();
                case "B":
                    return item.ToObject<B>();
            }

            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool CanWrite => false;
    }


    class Program
    {
        private const string json = @"
            [
                {
                'id': 0,
                'type': 'A'
                },
                {
                'id': 1,
                'type': 'B',
                'name': 'One'
                },
                {
                'id': 2,
                'type': 'A',
                'members': [
                    {
                    'id': 3,
                    'type': 'A'
                    }
                ]
                }
            ]
        ";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { Converters = { new MyConverter() } };
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IMember>>(json, settings);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in control of both the serialization and the deserialization, try using `TypeNameHandling.All` in your serializer settings on both serialize and deserialize.

When you have an abstract type like an interface, it doesn't know which concrete type to use. The outer concrete type can be specified in the `Deserialize` type parameter, but the inner types can't. Using `TypeNameHandling` lets you deserialize to an abstract type, but it will actually deserialize to the concrete type specified in `$type`.

The alternative is to deserialize to `JObject`s and then individually `ToObject<T>` on each of those, but then you have to do it on every inner object.

You can also use a custom `JsonConverter` but that's even more complexity.

Another alternative is to just not use interfaces for storing data if you can avoid it. If it's just a bunch of properties with no methods, it probably doesn't need an interface.

---

**Update:**

How about this modification to your custom `JsonConverter`:

```
case "A":
    return new A
    {
        ID = item["id"]?.Value<int>() ?? 0,
        Type = typeValue,
        Members = ((JArray)item["members"])?.ToObject<List<IMember>>(serializer)
    };
```

It's not pretty, but it works. You need to pass the serializer with your custom converter through on `ToObject` but if you do `item.ToObject<A>(serializer)` you get a stack overflow, so you need to only do it on the `members` property.

Comment: Your solution gets me over the hump.  Thanks.  You'd think the JsonConverter would be able to handle this.